# Initialising Spring AOP hangs the entire application after few successful requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

I have Spring 5.0.4 application with a Dispatcher servlet config file as `spring-web-servlet.xml` (spring-web being Dispatcher servlet name).
To enable AOP in the application, I made the entry `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` in `spring-web-servlet.xml` after including the namespace for aop.

The `pom.xml` has below entries:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

To use AOP, I created below Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("getApiPointcut()")
    public void logRequest(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
      //some logic here
    }

    @AfterReturning(value = "getApiPointcut()", returning = "returnValue")
    public void logResponse(Object returnValue) {
        //some logic here
    }

    @Pointcut("within(com.test.service.controller.*) " +
            " || within(com.test.service.api.GenericService)" +
            " || within(com.test.service.api.UserService)")
    public void getApiPointcut() {

    }


}
```

This class has two methods: logRequest() and logResponse().
Every API call will first go through logRequest() and before returning the response, logResponse() is called.

For the initial few requests (5-6), AOP works fine and I get the flow in MyAspect class for both the methods.

But after that, if I hit any API, flow goes through logRequest(), then the API class, and then it hangs. The API class calls the service class. But the flow never reaches the service class and hence never goes in logResponse() and the server does not return anything to the client. I checked the logs and there are no exceptions. I checked the heap memory usage too and it is not consumed fully. Even the threads are not fully occupied. (Checked these stats using jconsole).

If I disable AOP by removing `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` from `spring-web-servlet.xml` file, the server returns response for all the calls without any issue.

So, the conclusion that I made is enabling the AOP is causing the server to hang but I am not able to understand why.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The APIs (controller) on which I am trying to invoke AOP are annotated with @PreAuthorize. If I comment out the @PreAuthorize annotation, the application does not hang. Uncommenting the @PreAuthorize annotation again results in 5-6 successful requests and then the application hangs.
As @PreAuthorize also uses AOP, is there any case that I need to take care of when using my own AOP with @PreAuthorize?

**UPDATE 2**

The @PreAuthorize method on the API is as below:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_AUTH') and @myUtil.canRead(#userId) ")
```

If I remove the `hasAuthority('SOME_AUTH')` and keep the second check, the aplication works fine, but if I keep both or keep only hasAuthority() check, the application does not responds after a few successful responses.

**UPDATE 3**

The issue gets resolved if I annotate the API with @Transactional.
However, the code used to work without @Transactional when aop was disabled. So why does enabling AOP makes it necessary to have @Transactional on the API?

Comment: Are you sure methods are executed normally without any exception ? it cant be. try to change from AfterReturning to After advice, lets see whether that works.

Comment: Yes. I tried placing the method call in try-catch block but encountered no error.
The problem is that even if I comment out the entire MyAspect.java class, and just have <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> in spring-web-servlet.xml, the application starts to hang after a few successful requests.

Comment: @Barath The APIs (controller) on which I am trying to invoke AOP are annotated with PreAuthorize. If I comment out the PreAuthorize annotation, the application does not hang. Uncommenting the PreAuthorize annotation again results in 5-6 successful requests and then the application hangs. As PreAuthorize also uses AOP, is there any case that I need to take care of when using my own AOP with PreAuthorize?